# Minimum number if Common Items in 2 Dynamic Stacks

Tags: dynamic, linked-list, stack

I have a verbal algorithm question, thus I have no code yet. The question is this: How can I possibly create an algorithm such that I have 2 dynamic stacks, both can or can not have duplicate items of strings, for example I have 3 breads, 4 lemons and 2 pens in the first stack, say s1, and I have 5 breads, 3 lemons and 5 pens in the second stack, say s2. I want to find the number of duplicates in each stack, and print out the minimum number of duplicates in both lists, for example:

```
bread --> 3
lemon --> 3
pen --> 2
```

How can I traverse 2 stacks and print the number of duplicated occurrences until the end of stacks? If you are confused about anything, I can edit my question depending on your confusion. Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for the `C++` tag?

Comment: I added that in case if someone send an example code written in another language, because I only know C++, I know it's an algorithm question, but someone could send an example code that's why.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service, so don't expect someone to provide code.  When you tag C++, it is expected that a specific question concerning the C++ language is what is being posted, or a C++ program with a specific issue is posted.  .

Comment: I edited the post, sorry for thinking all possibilities and being a normal human being.